# how to decode base64Binary-to-string in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

Hi I am trying to convert my Base64 data to string in xslt but unable to do so.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">

  <xsl:template match="Data">  
    <xsl:element name="fos1">
      <xsl:value-of select="(saxon:base64Binary-to-string(
                             xs:base64Binary("Data"), 
                             "UTF8"))"/>       
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have one xml file also where i have stored base64 data the looks like below code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>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</Data>
```

Answer (score -1):

The call `xs:base64Binary("Data")` tries to create a base-64 value from the character string "Data", which is not a legal base-64 string.  So you should be getting an error message saying roughly that.  Hmm.  You didn't mention an error message; you didn't explain what exactly you mean by "unable to do so".  Next time, provide more information, ok?

If you want to apply the function to the string value of the `Data` element, bear in mind that you are making the call in an expression located in a template which matches that element.  You almost certainly want to replace the call in the current expression with something like `xs:base64Binary(.)`.